# res.redirect showing old information after form submission?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a node.js app in which I created a user profile page. I made it editable so they can update their name if they want to.

However, when I click the 'Save Changes' button on the form, it redirects to the correct page but shows the old information. Only once you refresh the page or navigate away from it does the updated information show.

submission form html:

```
<form action="./profile" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<%= name %>" 
name="name"> 
</div>
<div class="form-group" >
    <label for="">email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<%= email %>" readonly>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><a href="profileEditor"> 
</a> Save Changes</button>
    </div>
    <p>&nbsp; &nbsp;</p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-dismiss"><a href="./profile">Exit</a> 
</button></a>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

parts of index.js (in my routes folder)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { ensureAuthenticated } = require('../config/auth');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../models/User');

router.post('/', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
   updateRecord(req,res);
   res.redirect('/profile');
});

function updateRecord(req, res) {
User.findOne({_id:req.user.id},(err,doc)=>{
 //this will give you the document what you want to update.. then 
doc.name = req.body.name;
doc.save(function(err,doc){
}); 
});   
}

module.exports = router;
```

under my router.post function, the res.redirect works and sends the user to '/profile' but doesn't show the updated database info. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use findOneAndUpdate() function to update user profile. Try as below:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { ensureAuthenticated } = require('../config/auth');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../models/User');

router.post('/', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.user.id},{name: req.body.name},{new: true},(err,doc)=>{
       console.log('#### Updated Record ####',doc);
       res.redirect('/profile');
  });   
});



module.exports = router;
```