# Node js application not showing updated page after res.redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session

I'm trying to add an item to shopping cart using express-session, after "add to cart" button is clicked, res.redirect should redirect to shopping cart page.  But item quantity on redirected shopping cart page is not updated, unless I refresh the page by manually clicking shopping cart button.

I have thought it might be related to asynchronous and tried adding setTimeout function to delay the page refreshing and didn't work. Also have tried async/await, didn't work. And I found my question is very similar to [res.redirect showing old information after form submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54472404/res-redirect-showing-old-information-after-form-submission), but the answer suggested to combine two functions into one so res.redirect will work. Since my code has sql involves so I'm not sure if the two functions can be combined.  Below is my router.post code.

```
router.post('/:idx', async function (req, res) {
  var productId = req.params.idx
  cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {});

      var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM prod.product_list_details WHERE idx = ?'
      await   conn.query(queryString, productId,   function (err, rows) {
            if (err) throw err;
            cart_id = rows[0].idx
            cart_data = rows[0];
            cart.add(cart_data, cart_id)
            // cart.increment(cart_id)
            req.session.cart = cart;
            console.log(req.session.cart)
            res.locals.session = req.session;
            // callback();
            // res.redirect('/shopping-cart');
           })
           setTimeout(() => {
            res.redirect('../shopping-cart');
          }, 2000)
});
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks much!

Comment: just curious are you using knex to connect with the database?

Comment: hi, i'm using mysql database.